# Column does not exist error for all columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I removed all the spaces on header row before reading it into a dataframe. checked it again on python and here are the column names:

```
Index(['School_ID', 'NAME_OF_SCHOOL', 'Elementary,Middle,orHighSchool',
       'Street_Address', 'City', 'State', 'ZIP_Code', 'Phone_Number', 'Link',
       'Network_Manager', 'Collaborative_Name',
       'Adequate_Yearly_Progress_Made_', 'Track_Schedule',
       'CPS_Performance_Policy_Status', 'CPS_Performance_Policy_Level',
       'HEALTHY_SCHOOL_CERTIFIED', 'Safety_Icon', 'SAFETY_SCORE',
       'Family_Involvement_Icon', 'Family_Involvement_Score',
       'Environment_Icon', 'Environment_Score', 'Instruction_Icon',
       'Instruction_Score', 'Leaders_Icon', 'Leaders_Score', 'Teachers_Icon',
       'Teachers_Score', 'Parent_Engagement_Icon', 'Parent_Engagement_Score',
       'Parent_Environment_Icon', 'Parent_Environment_Score',
       'AVERAGE_STUDENT_ATTENDANCE', 'Rate_of_Misconducts__per_100_students_',
       'Average_Teacher_Attendance',
       'Individualized_Education_Program_Compliance_Rate', 'Pk_2_Literacy__',
       'Pk_2_Math__', 'Gr3_5_Grade_Level_Math__', 'Gr3_5_Grade_Level_Read__',
       'Gr3_5_Keep_Pace_Read__', 'Gr3_5_Keep_Pace_Math__',
       'Gr6_8_Grade_Level_Math__', 'Gr6_8_Grade_Level_Read__',
       'Gr6_8_Keep_Pace_Math_', 'Gr6_8_Keep_Pace_Read__',
       'Gr_8_Explore_Math__', 'Gr_8_Explore_Read__', 'ISAT_Exceeding_Math__',
       'ISAT_Exceeding_Reading__', 'ISAT_Value_Add_Math',
       'ISAT_Value_Add_Read', 'ISAT_Value_Add_Color_Math',
       'ISAT_Value_Add_Color_Read', 'Students_Taking__Algebra__',
       'Students_Passing__Algebra__', '9thGradeEXPLORE(2009)',
       '9thGradeEXPLORE(2010)', '10thGradePLAN(2009)', '10thGradePLAN(2010)',
       'Net_Change_EXPLORE_and_PLAN', '11thGradeAverageACT(2011)',
       'Net_Change_PLAN_and_ACT', 'College_Eligibility__', 'Graduation_Rate__',
       'College_Enrollment_Rate__', 'COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT',
       'General_Services_Route', 'Freshman_on_Track_Rate__', 'X_COORDINATE',
       'Y_COORDINATE', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER',
       'COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME', 'Ward', 'Police_District', 'Location'],
      dtype='object')
```

For some reason only `select *` works and for everything else I do I get a column does not exist error like this:

```
%sql select count(distinct "School_ID") from chicago_schools;
```

```
 * postgresql://postgres:***@localhost:5432/table1
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "school_id" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(distinct School_ID) from chicago_schools;
                              ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "chicago_schools.School_ID".
```

(same with `chicago_schools.School_ID`)

Using single quotes returns me the column name itself.

```
%sql select 'NAME_OF_SCHOOL' from chicago_schools limit 2;
```

```
 * postgresql://postgres:***@localhost:5432/table1
2 rows affected.

?column?
NAME_OF_SCHOOL
NAME_OF_SCHOOL
```

Using no quotes returns no columns exist error again.
I am using sqlalchemy 1.3.9,psycopg 2.9.1 & postgres 13.4.

Here are the column names and data types of some of the columns.

```
%sql SELECT column_name,data_type \
FROM information_schema.columns \
WHERE table_name = 'chicago_schools';
```

```
column_name                   data_type
ISAT_Exceeding_Math__         double precision
ISAT_Exceeding_Reading__      double precision
ISAT_Value_Add_Math           double precision
ISAT_Value_Add_Read           double precision
SAFETY_SCORE                  double precision
Environment_Score             double precision
School_ID                      bigint
COLLEGE_ENROLLMENT             bigint
General_Services_Route         bigint
Instruction_Score              double precision
X_COORDINATE                   double precision
Y_COORDINATE                   double precision
Latitude                       double precision
Longitude                      double precision
COMMUNITY_AREA_NUMBER          bigint
ZIP_Code                       bigint
Ward                           bigint
Police_District                bigint
index                          bigint
Leaders_Icon                   text
Leaders_Score                  text
```

The rest are text too

Comment: Did you tried without ´ or " around column name. In the last test you did, you actually select text NAME_OF_SCHOOL because of quotes, instead of value of column NAME_OF_SCHOOL

Comment: Postgrsql column names are lower case by default, so if they weren't double-quoted in the create table statement they will be lower case.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes i have, with or without single quotes, double quotes and ` too.

Comment: What are the column name displayed when you do select * ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb all the column names are exactly the same as in the dataframe, I have checked this already.

Comment: When you do get  when entering comands : \d and then \d chicago_shcools

Comment: @PtitXav I get ``` 
Schema Name Type Owner
public chicago_schools table postgres
```
```
Column                            Type    Modifiers
index                            bigint 
School_ID                    bigint 
NAME_OF_SCHOOL    text 
Elementary,Middle,orHighSchool text 
``` and the remaining rows too

Comment: Can you try : select concat(´-‘.column _name,’-‘) from information… this to check if you have no space left in column names

Comment: @PtitXav executed it, no spaces in all the column names.

Comment: Did you try the select "chicago_schools"."NAME_OF_SCHOOL" from "chicago_schools"?

Comment: @PtitXav tried "chicago_schools"."NAME_OF_SCHOOL" and "chicago_schools.NAME_OF_SCHOOL", same errors again.

Comment: @PtitXav I changed all the column names to lower case,made sure the names consist of alphabets and underscore only and now it works. Thanks for your help.